# UserControl with autosized form and flowpanel not resizing the height inside a splitpanel

Tags: winforms

I'm having some issues trying to adapt my project to use UserControls.
now I have this setup, and the height of my userControl is not auto resizing.

```
SplitPanel
    SplitPanel.panel1
        MyUserControl -> autosize true, dock top, achor top left
            Form -> autosize true
                Button -> dock top
                FlowLayout -> dock top, leftToRight, autosize true
                    some elements: label, dropdown, button
    SplitPanel.panel2
        other stuffs
```

**Full sized splitPanel**

[image]

**Resized split panel, control not resized**

[image]

**User Control full size**

[image]

**User control resized (flowLayout resized)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that the Control don't resize itself and I needed to resize myself when the flowPanel resizes:

```
 private void flowLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var pnl = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
     pnl.Parent.Size = new Size(pnl.Width, pnl.Height + collapseButtonHeight);
 }
```